# Find $\int {x}(\frac{1}{2}x-1)^{-1/2}dx$

Tags: integration

> Find $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x-1}}dx$$

So I think i should do these by a substitution with $u=\frac{1}{2}x-1$ but when did this I got is more complex. Is this the right approach.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Use the linearity of integration and the power rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I think i should do these by a substitution with $u=\frac{1}{2}x-1$ but when did this I got is more complex.

Not really. You should get
$$ \int 2\frac{2u+2}{\sqrt u}\, du $$ 
which is *simpler* than what you started with. Having many terms *above* the fraction bar is very cheap, complexity-wise, because you can use linearity to split them into several separater integrals:
$$ \int 2\frac{2u+2}{\sqrt u}\, du = 4\int\frac{u}{\sqrt u}\,du + 4\int \frac{1}{\sqrt u}\,du $$ 
and each of these is easily doable with the power rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$t=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x-1}$$ then we get $$x=2(t^2+1)$$ and $$dx=4tdt$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**  For more simple calculations, use the substitution $u=x-2 \longrightarrow \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}u$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following manipulation to calculate the integral without any substitution :
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}x-1}}&=\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{x-2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}(x-2+2)}{\sqrt{x-2}}\\
&=\sqrt{2(x-2)}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x-2}}
\end{align}
Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on to @HenningMakholm's answer, really.

Note that $$\frac{u}{\sqrt{u}}=\sqrt{u}$$
So the integral boils down to $$4\int u^{1/2}du+4\int u^{-1/2}du$$
Which are easy with the power rule.